# processmaker value based parallel task

Tags: parallel-processing, processmaker

I required to split my task for multiple users parallelly , where the split condition depends upon the vaiable value input by user

For example :
consider 100 pages of work , a person can able to do 25 pages , so we have to split for 4 members parallely
if it is 150 pages , the split qty is 6 members

kindly suggest me the possible ways by using ProcessMaker

I tried by using Marker type as Parallel & set the Assignment rules as Parallel Assignment & Value base Assignment

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.